# In Io language, what's the difference between 1 proto and 1 type?

Tags: programming-languages, prototype, iolanguage

```
Io> 1 proto == Number
==> true
Io> 1 type == Number
==> false
Io> 1 proto
==> 0
Io> 1 type
==> Number
```

I'm very confused about this. Does anyone have ideas about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because *type* is a sequence whereas *protos* are a list of objects.

```
Io> (1 proto) type
==> Number

Io> 1 hasProto("Number")
==> false

Io> 1 hasProto(Number)
==> true

Io> (1 type) type
==> Sequence

Io> 1 type == "Number"
==> true
```

What is interesting is that...

```
Io> 1 protos
==> list(0)
```

... instead of returning `list(Number)`.   But with 0 (zero) being a Number object then I suspects this doesn't cause protos a problem!